# Import IntelliJ formatter options into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm the only one using eclipse in an all-IntelliJ team. Is there any way I can have eclipse format the code with the same style as the default IntelliJ formatter does, without having to manually adapt everything?

Something like the opposite to the [IntelliJ eclipse formatter plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546)

Comment: switch to intelliJ (don't fight the team and idea) :-)

Comment: I WILL RESIST!! Or they will suffer my changesets!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This subject has come up many times over the years in the IntelliJ IDEA forums. Having common code formatting definitions is probably one of the biggest sticking points in a poly-IDE environment. There is not a way to go from IDEA formatting rules to Eclipse formatting rules. Since IDEA users tend to be in the minority in groups, there tends to be a "if you want to use the odd ball IDE (i.e. IntelliJ IDEA), then *you* have to deal with keeping things in sync". Thus the availability of the IntelliJ eclipse formatter plugin you mention, but not the other way around.

Comment: Still true 5 years later, although by now, the eclipse folks are more of the minority, at least in the teams I am working with ...

Comment: @GhostCat It's not just your team. Snyk survey results released yesterday shows that IDEA has 45% of the JVM IDE market, Eclipse 38% https://snyk.io/blog/jvm-ecosystem-report-2018-tools

Comment: well, 45% vs 38% - hard to call minority :)

Comment: @GhostCat Still true +4 years.

Comment: 2020 checking in, it's Eclipse team that does not want to be open.